# MySql, php: Read from 2 Tables with same User ID

Tags: php, mysql, join

Hello Sorry for the previously Post:
I habe a table ´Nachrichten´ and a table 'user'.
I want the rows from 'Nachrichten' where Quelle is like $_SESSION["id"]. Quelle is a UserID. Now I need the rows from 'user' where ID is like $_SESSION["id"], too beacause I need the name and lastname from the user: This is my Query but I get no faild but no results too. Thanks for support.

```
$abfrage = "SELECT * FROM Nachrichten n JOIN user u ON u.id = n.Quelle WHERE n.Quelle LIKE '".$_SESSION["id"]."'";
            $ergebnis = mysql_query($abfrage);
            while($row = mysql_fetch_object($ergebnis))
            {
                $id = $row["n"]->ID; $ziel = $row["n"]->Ziel; $uhrzeit = $row["n"]->Uhrzeit; $gelesen = $row["n"]->Gelesen; $inhalt = $row["n"]->Inhalt; $vorname = $row["u"]->Vorname; $nachname = $row["u"]->Nachname; 
                kontakt($ziel, $vorname, $nachname, $uhrzeit, $gelesen);
                echo "hjfe";
            }
```

Comment: Doesn't work means? Please add example data, expected output and your relevant table structure.

Comment: Do Nachrichten and user relate in some way? Also a search like "LIKE SESSION[id] is really unusual. Either you want THAT session id or you don't!

Comment: If you have a row from user that has a relationship to Nachrichten table then you should probably use a JOIN or LEFT JOIN. With this query you are tring to grab all records from both tables... We need more info in order to help.

Comment: Maybe you want to echo the results?

Comment: first of all an syntax check..
i want the information from nachrichten where quelle is like SessionID, and i need the table user ID, because i need the name from table user....
the query gives me nothing.. i tried it with the join below but i gaves me nothing tough

Answer (score 0):

Just guessing...

```
$abfrage = "
SELECT * 
  FROM Nachrichten n
  JOIN user u
    ON u.id = n.Quelle
 WHERE n.Quelle = '{$_SESSION['id']}';
";
```